# Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли ошибки в этих двух предложениях, и если есть, то в чём они заключаются

Tags: пунктуация

1. Как быть, если ты – это некрасивый человек, если нельзя носить ту одежду, которая нравится?
2. Что такое женский бюст и мужской торс знают даже дети.

Answer (score 1):

*Как быть, если ты некрасивый человек, если нельзя носить ту одежду, которая нравится?*

*Что такое женский бюст и мужской торс, знают даже дети.*

Ставят тире и после него **и слова "это"** объясняют незнакомые предметы, явления или по новому раскрывают их сущность. В Вашей фразе ничего такого нет.

Comment: После долгих поисков, но мне не верят:Марина Елисеева, г. Санкт-Петербург, журнал "Русский язык" №24/2002. Правила постановки тире (прилагаю скриншоты источника).
1.Тире ставится перед словом "это" , стоящим между подлежащим и сказуемым.
2.Если подлежащие выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое - существительным в именительном падеже, тире ставится в ряде случаев, в частности, в таком, как первое предложение:при логическом выделении местоимения.

Comment: Всё равно утверждают, что это ошибка, хотя: Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В.Кабанова Н.П. «Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию» М.-1999, параграф 79.

Comment: 53. Тире ставится перед словами это, это есть, вот, значит, это значит, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему. 
Например: Кремль – это сокровищница русского зодчества, творение великих мастеров, живая летопись многовековой истории (Из газет). Все прошедшее, настоящее и будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий (Горький). 
Ср.: Самая поздняя осень – это когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой» (Пришвин) (в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение).

Comment: 58. Тире обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое – именительным падежом существительного, например: ...Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Чехов); Я ужасно рада, что ты мой брат (Л. Толстой); Он порча, он чума, он язва здешних мест (Крылов). 
Тире в этом случае ставится при противопоставлении или при логическом подчеркивании сказуемого, например: Ты – старый ребенок, теоретик, а я – молодой старик и практик... (Чехов); Я – фабрикант, ты – судовладелец... (Горький); Не я, не я, а ты – вредоносный элемент (Федин).

Answer (score 0):

1) Как быть, если **ты – это некрасивый человек**, если нельзя носить ту одежду, которая нравится?

Тире ставится **перед словом-связкой "это"** в обязательном порядке, что связано с **особой структурой таких предложения** (они строятся по принципу именительного темы). При этом подлежащее и сказуемое могут быть выражены **различными частями** речи.

2) Что такое женский бюст и мужской торс, знают даже дети.

Здесь **изъяснительное сказуемое стоит на первом месте**, поэтому в некоторых случаях **возможны пауза и тире:** Как рассказывал учитель – долго слушал у окна я. И что такое "интернированный" ― я тоже не знала.

Но чаще встречается **обычная постановка запятой:** Что такое любовь, я не знаю. Что такое Америка, здесь представляют плохо. Солдаты, скорее всего, не знали про то, что красота спасёт мир, но **что такое красота,** оба они, в общем, знали.